# No visible @interface for 'FIRTrace' declares the selector 'incrementCounterNamed'. FirebasePlugin.m

Tags: swift, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have this problem reported in the title, I can't build my app on my iOS, it's the only error that happens.

No visible @interface for 'FIRTrace' declares the selector 'incrementCounterNamed'. FirebasePlugin.m
[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuebY.png)

this is my package.json

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/base64-to-gallery": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.15.1",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/safari-view-controller": "^5.15.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-base64-to-gallery": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-lib": "^9.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller": "^1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "3.0.0",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "1.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.9.2",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "1.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "2.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "^3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.9",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.2",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.8.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "~3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "~2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "~6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-speechrecognition": "^1.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "xcode": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION": "27.+",
        "FCM_VERSION": "11.6.2"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-speechrecognition": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {},
      "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-base64-to-gallery": {},
      "cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller": {}
    }

}
}
```

I Tried to update my pods and deintegrate, cache clean, but don't works.

Thank you all

Comment: I have exact same problem

Comment: No body? Same problem here.

Comment: @All Have you found any solution for this? I am facing same issue.